# Update user profile picture using entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, entities, users

I am trying to update the user profile picture using entity_metadata_wrapper. But I am getting

> "Unknown data property picture." error.

When I check the user property info, I cant see the picture field as well. Below is my example code:

```
$user = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $form_state['entity_id']);
if (isset($form_state['values']['user_profile_pic'])) {
   $file = file_load($form_state['values']['user_profile_pic']);
   $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
   file_save($file);
$user->picture = $file;
}
```

[image: user entity wrapper]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out :

```
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $form_state['entity_id']);
//- Get the user object.
  $user = $wrapper->value();
  if (isset($form_state['values']['user_profile_pic'])) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['user_profile_pic']);
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
    $edit = array(
      'picture' => $file,
    );
    user_save($user, $edit);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks berramou, but I am still getting "Unknown data property picture." entityMetadataWrapperexception error while debugging with xdebug. When I use $user->getPropertyInfo(), i cant get the picture field property associated with user, may be I think that is where something is wrong. I checked the /admin/config/people/accounts page and enabled the user pictures as well. But could not figure out what is the root cause.

Comment: Try this i edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks berramou, really appreciate it. I did fix the issue with similar approach but I am not sure if it is the correct way. You can see that I have already declared $user variable as entity_metadata_wrapper in my example and declaring another user object with user_load function to save the picture is not the best way?? Again not sure about this, just wanted to know your thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, if you want to use `entity_metadata_wrapper` instead of `user_load`, see the code bellow, i have edited my answer again :) **Note** `wrapper->value()` to get the user object, it's important. Good Luck.

Comment: You are Welcome.